# Artifactory Jenkins plugin publishing Python projects

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I am building out a jenkins system to compile and publish a large number of python projects to my Artifactory server.  I do not want to use `twine` or `pip` to publish, because I want to utilize Artifactory builds.

The Artifactory API docs have notes for Java, Javascript, and a few other languages, but nothing for Python projects.

Am I correct in assuming that I am supposed to use the generic server.upload api for python projects?

Will artifactory automatically pull the pypi metadata from the wheel file I upload?

Comment: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/PyPI+Repositories - this link have different ways that can be used for publishing. Hope so this helps

Comment: Problem is that’s using setuptools.  I want to use the Jenkins artifactory plugin so I have access to all the property systems and build systems inside artifactory for easy promotions and such